# How to store multiple values from user to array upto particular size?

Tags: c#, arrays, input

I am trying to get a values from user and store it in a array up to particular size. my code looks like

```
int n = int.parse(Console.ReadLine());
string[] samples = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');
int[] scores = Array.ConvertAll(samples, Int32.Parse);
```

the above code works but it doesn't stops after getting `n` inputs and it allow me to store values after `n` inputs. how do i make it stop getting inputs after `n` inputs and i want to get all inputs in single space separated line. for eg:

```
9
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

should i use for loop to make that possible?

Comment: Do `Console.ReadLine` in loop which runs till n.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> how do i make it stop getting inputs after n inputs

Meaning, what? Exactly? According to the code, you appear to require all inputs on a single line, separated by spaces. You can ignore all inputs beyond `n` like this:

```
string[] samples = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ').Take(n).ToArray();
```

If that's not what you want, please improve the question so that it's more clear exactly what you've tried, what the code you have does now, and what you want it to do instead.

Note that other alternatives include:

- Requiring the user to enter a separate number on each line. In this case, you can do as suggested in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43622971/how-to-store-multiple-values-from-user-to-array-upto-particular-size/43623000?noredirect=1#comment74295022_43622971), and put the data entry (i.e. the call to `Console.ReadLine()`) into a loop. For example:

```cs
string[] samples = new string[n];
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    samples[i] = Console.ReadLine();
}
```

- Handle the user input one key at a time, terminating the input once the user has entered the required number of values, regardless of spaces, line-breaks, etc. This is a lot more complicated approach, so I won't bother writing a code example for that, given that it doesn't appear necessary at the moment.

Comment: i guess OP wants to take only n inputs.`it allow me to input values after n inputs`.

Comment: @Nikhil: yes. And, your point? Did you read my answer? Do you understand that, according to the code the OP's posted, all `n` inputs are entered in a single line?

Comment: @PeterDuniho i edited my question can you able to understand now and by the way i used the code you suggested it works.

Comment: @pkarthicbz: thanks for the edit. That suggests to me that my original answer is the one you're looking for. If you need something more elaborate, please explain more precisely what that is.

Comment: @PeterDuniho is there any way to use `for` loop for getting values in single space seperated line?

Comment: @PeterDuniho i don't want to prompt the user every time to input the value but  i want the  user to input the values in single space separated line.

Comment: @pkarthicbz: _"is there any way to use for loop for getting values in single space seperated line?"_ -- yes, that would be the second bullet-point in my answer above. Is that needed in your scenario?

Comment: @PeterDuniho not needed at this time just curiosity :)