# array of integer input from user

Tags: c#, arrays

I have a question related to filling it in an array. In the program I have to write I am given "input from user: different number of numbers separated by space (for example: 1 4 6 2)". These numbers must be entered in an array that will be used later.
The problem is the following how to insert in the array an indefinite number of numbers written on one line with space between them without determining their number in advance?

Comment: Assuming your input is a string from the user, use string.split() to return an array. Documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netcore-3.1 . Whether you want to return the string array or convert to an integer array after is up to you.

Comment: I understand, thank you very much

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to store multiple values from user to array upto particular size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43622971/how-to-store-multiple-values-from-user-to-array-upto-particular-size)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the easier thing to do would be to split input string by space and then use Linq to map each element to an int:

```
String userInput = "1 4 6 2";
int[] ints = userInput.Split(' ').Select(x => Int32.Parse(x)).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

this is the answer to my question. I wish I had helped someone.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace Stack_Sum
 {
class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Stack<int> numbers = new Stack<int>();
        string input = Console.ReadLine();
        string[] number = Regex.Split(input, @"\D+");
        foreach (string value in number)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
            {
                int i = int.Parse(value);
                Console.WriteLine("Number: {0}", i);
            }
        }

    }

  }
}
```